# Parametrise a javascript file to render REST API calls in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a REST API and I am able to do calls using urls like the following:

```js
'http://localhost:8888/items/q?item=2'
```

Since the response is not rendered in html, I created item.html and item.js.
In item.js I have built a logic to async fetch the data from my REST API and when I hardcode a query (like the above) inside item.js and call item.html the response renders the desired way.

Now, I have another html page, home.html, where there is some logic that renders a list of calls to the API. For example a rendered home.html might look like this:

```js
'http://localhost:8888/items/q?item=1'
'http://localhost:8888/items/q?item=3'
'http://localhost:8888/items/q?item=345'
'http://localhost:8888/items/q?item=768'
'http://localhost:8888/items/q?item=9876'
...
```

where each line above is a rendered value of a handlebars variable `{{item_link}}` like in this div:

```html
<a href="{{item_link}}" target="_blank">Show item info</a>
```

Is there a way to convert the logic of having a hardcoded link value in item.js in order to render item.html, and instead each time I call item.html pass the desired link value (from those rendered from home.html shown above) and in a way parametrise item.js so I will be able to render with item.html any response of a successful call to this REST API? Thanks!